# Redirecionando URLs do mesmo domínio via htaccess

Tags: htaccess, url, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Eu gostaria de direcionar por meio do `htaccess` duas `url` do mesmo domínio, do tipo 301. Exemplo:

Redirecionar `meusite.com.br/customer-service` para `meusite.com.br/central-atendimento`

Eu tentei o seguinte código abaixo no arquivo `.htaccess` do meu servidor, porém não funcionou:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://meusite.com.br/customer-service [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://meusite.com.br/central-atendimento$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução desse problema é algo bem simples. No arquivo `.htaccess` do seu servidor, basta somente inserir o seguinte código abaixo:

```
redirect 301 /url-antiga /url-nova
```

Ou seja, no meu caso, ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
redirect 301 /customer-service /central-atendimento
```

Lembrando que com esse código, não é necessário colocar o caminho base do seu site antes da barra. Outra coisa, é que o código deve ser colocado dentro de uma tag:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c></IfModule>`

Exemplo no meu caso:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    redirect 301 /customer-service /central-atendimento
</IfModule>
```